# EntityRef missing from the response for Transaction Query

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

We have an issue with the response for Transaction Query of QuickBooks desktop. According to this:
https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbdesktop/docs/api-reference/qbdesktop/transactionquery

There should be an EntityRef in the response which shows the Vendor, Customer, etc for the transaction. However, in one of our customer's instances, the response does not include this element for transactions of type JournalEntry, Invoice, ItemReceipt.

We are using a desktop application to send and receive XML responses from QuickBooks. Does anyone know any reason this might be happening? I thought it could be permission issue but I couldn't reproduce it in my sandbox instance to verify.

Appreciate your help.